# Magento:Custom code in abstract class

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, abstract-class

My requirement is to change the order of checkout steps. I have a custom module (Customization with checkout structure) for checkout.

I want to change the function `_getStepCodes()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php` (to change the order of checkout order). But I understood that abstract classes cannot be rewritten or overridden.

I want to keep all my changes to my custom module only "Company_CustCheckout". ie, the default checkout should work if my custom module is disabled.

I have copied the function `_getStepCodes()` to `app/code/local/Company/CustCheckout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`

```
<?php
class Company_CustCheckout_Block_Onepage_Abstract extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Abstract
{
    protected function _getStepCodes()
    {
        Mage::log('fdg',null,'order.log');
        return array('login', 'review', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment');
    }
}
```

But the log value is not printing, which means it is not entering the function in my module.

I haven't added any changes in module config.xml file.

How is it possible to add custom code in the function. 
How is it possible to change the order of checkout process.

Please help

Comment: Is there any clue??